# SQlite: Failed to open Database - directory is existent

Tags: android, sqlite

Good day!

I have issues implementing a DataBase into my App.
The issue that baffles me is that I imported a Database called itemsDB which worked for me. If I use any other database (lets talk about **myDB.db**) I have the issue of a non existent directory.

It seems like a lot of people have that issue, but I check if the DB is existent in the Advice File Explorer and it is:

[image: myDB.db is existant in the phone directory]

So this rules out most issues addressed in the other posts.

So I said everything is working with **itemDB**, this means if I use:

```
private static String DB_Name = "itemsDB.db";
private String DB_table = "Items_neu";
```

everything works.

If I want to use my new DataBank "myDB.db" I won't find my new asset in the Device. I checked with:

```
Cursor check;
    check = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
    if (check.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( !check.isAfterLast() ) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,  "Table Name=> "+check.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("table name:", check.getString(0));
            check.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

Which yields only "android_metadata" as the only table.
For **myItem.db** I find the correct table which is *Item_neu* aswell.

Let us analyse my Code now please:

```html
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_Path ="";

    private static String DB_Name = "myDB.db";
//    private static String DB_Name = "itemsDB.db";
    private String DB_table = "tableItems";
//    private String DB_table = "Items_neu";

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;


    private Context mContext = null;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_Name, null, 1);
        DB_Path = "/data/data/"+ context.getPackageName()+"/databases/";
        this.mContext = context;
    }
```

I edited my a checkDataBase method, which you can find at the end of the post.

```
The logchat gives me the following errors: (updated)
2018-10-19 16:32:56.437 1053-1053/com.example.chris.projectartifact E/Does DB exsist?:: Yes it does indeed exsits Christian!!!
2018-10-19 16:32:58.157 1053-1053/com.example.chris.projectartifact E/table name:: android_metadata
2018-10-19 16:32:58.158 1053-1053/com.example.chris.projectartifact E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
2018-10-19 16:32:58.161 1053-1053/com.example.chris.projectartifact E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chris.projectartifact, PID: 1053
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tableItems (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tableItems, (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:925)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:536)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1397)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1331)
        at com.example.chris.projectartifact.DBHelper.getAllItems(DBHelper.java:181)
        at com.example.chris.projectartifact.bb_Items.itemActivity$2.onClick(itemActivity.java:126)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
        at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:135)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
2018-10-19 16:32:58.761 2862-2862/com.example.chris.projectartifact E/MemoryLeakMonitorManager: MemoryLeakMonitor.jar is not exist!
2018-10-19 16:32:58.764 2862-2862/com.example.chris.projectartifact E/Minikin: Could not get cmap table size!
```

So summarizing:

- I can not edit new Databases to my Application
- Every new Database yields the error of not being a existent directory

If by any chances some can help me with my struggle, I would be very happy about that.

Edit: Here is some progress I made by myself. I edited a new CheckDataBase, which yields that the Database is existant and it just can not find the table

```
private boolean checkDataBase_new() {
        File databasePath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_Name);
        if(databasePath.exists()){
            Log.e("Does DB exsist?:","Yes it does indeed exsits Christian!!!");
        }else{
            Log.e("Does DB exsist?:","No that is causing the issue!");
        }
        /* Thoughts: So the DB Path for myDB exists, and we can find it. But there is just no readable table! */
        return databasePath.exists();
    }
```

With best regards
CG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, after a few hours I finally found out what caused my issue!

**When copying the Database in the Assets folder renamed the DB which apparently led to a lot of problems.**

So Boys, do not rename your DB's when copying them in the asset folder!